# The cost of performing analyzePattern() and factorize() in Eigen library Compute()

Tags: c++, eigen

I am referring to the [The Compute Step](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) section in Eigen documentation:

> In the `compute()` function, the matrix is generally factorized:
>
> ....
>
> For this class of solvers precisely,
>   the compute step is further subdivided into `analyzePattern()` and
>   `factorize()`.
>
> The goal of `analyzePattern()` is to reorder the nonzero elements of the
>   matrix, such that the factorization step creates less fill-in. This
>   step exploits only the structure of the matrix. **Hence, the results of
>   this step can be used for other linear systems where the matrix has
>   the same structure.** ....
>
> In `factorize()`, the factors of the coefficient matrix are computed.
>   This step should be called each time the values of the matrix change.
>   **However, the structural pattern of the matrix should not change
>   between multiple calls.**

The documentation for  [analyzePattern()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#aa907ff958c4f4855145091d2686f3a8a)

> Compute the column permutation to minimize the fill-in
>
> - Apply this permutation to the input matrix -
> - Compute the column elimination tree on the permuted matrix
> - Postorder the elimination tree and the column permutation

and [factorize()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#a39858b0e72f2659d596364e252b34cbc)

> Numerical factorization Interleaved with the symbolic factorization On
>   exit, info is
>
> = 0: successful factorization
>
> 0: if info = i, and i is
>
> <= A->ncol: U(i,i) is exactly zero. The factorization has
>        been completed, but the factor U is exactly singular,
>        and division by zero will occur if it is used to solve a
>        system of equations.
>
> > A->ncol: number of bytes allocated when memory allocation
> >         failure occurred, plus A->ncol. If lwork = -1, it is
> >         the estimated amount of space needed, plus A->ncol.

My question is, do we know the relative cost of calling `analyzePattern()` and  `factorize()`?

This question is important to me because my application has a stable matrix structure but constantly changing coefficient matrix. Example: in FEM model, FEM users often leave the element connection unchanged, but always change the element sizes in order to get the best design.

So if `analyzePattern()` is a lot expensive than `factorize()`, then I can take advantage of this fact and rewrite my code. If no, I can just stick to the `compute()` function and rerun `analyzePattern()` every time the element sizes change.

Comment: Why not measure the difference for your specific pattern and decide based on that?

Comment: @AviGinsburg, I can. But I guess it will benefit the internet at large if the performance of these two functions are documented ( as a SO Q&A) on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a lot on the structure of the matrix. In my experience, the symbolic part is usually much cheaper than the numerical part, however, according to a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41900027/1641621), it is sometimes the converse. So I'm afraid you'll never know for sure until you bench.

Comment: may I ask, what do you use sparse solver for? Mine is finite element model.

Comment: Same here, but the structure will still depend a lot on the dimension of the domain (1D, 2D, 3D) and kinds of elements.