# Copy SimplicialLLT object in Eigen

Tags: eigen, rcppeigen

I apologies in advance if this is an easy question but I am still learning Eigen.

I am creating two `Eigen::SimplicialLLT` objects

```
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Omegachol1;
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Omegachol2;
Omegachol1.compute(Omega1);
Omegachol2.compute(Omega2);
```

and next, I would need to use one of them for other calculations and therefore I need to assign a new SimplicialLLT object to one of them (reusing the initial object is of course possible but very tedious and the code would quickly become unreadable).

I tried something like

```
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Omegachol = Omegachol1;
```

but it does not work.

Is there a way to copy SimplicialLLT object and reuse them?

Based on my understanding, this is not a duplicate of [Re-use Eigen::SimplicialLLT's symbolic decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899666/re-use-eigensimplicialllts-symbolic-decomposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solvers objects are neither copyable nor movable. I suggest using a reference to the solver object:

```cpp
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Omegachol1;
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Omegachol2;
Omegachol1.compute(Omega1);
Omegachol2.compute(Omega2);

Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> & Omegachol1_ref = Omegachol1
```

EDIT: Apparently also for Eigen::SimplicialLLT the solve method is non-const, so you will need a non-const reference.

Comment: Note that some other solver objects, e.g. SparseLU have a non-const solve method.